# IContextMenu::InvokeCommand error Code 0x80270000 on windows 7

Tags: c++

i have the following code to delete the file. this code is work fine on winXP. but when i run on windows 7 it will not delete the file. i get the Error code 0x80270000 when InvokeCommand statement is executed.

```
HRESULT hr = m_psfCurFolder->GetUIObjectOf(AfxGetMainWnd()->m_hWnd,
    uiCount, 
    (LPCITEMIDLIST*)aPidls, 
    IID_IContextMenu, 
    NULL, 
    (LPVOID*)&pcm);

    if (SUCCEEDED (hr))
    {
        HMENU hPopup = CreatePopupMenu();
        hr = pcm->QueryContextMenu(hPopup, 0, 1, 0x7fff, CMF_NORMAL);

        if (SUCCEEDED (hr))
        {
                CMINVOKECOMMANDINFO cmi;
                cmi.cbSize = sizeof(CMINVOKECOMMANDINFO);
                cmi.fMask =   CMIC_MASK_ASYNCOK;
                cmi.hwnd = (HWND) GetParent();
                cmi.lpVerb = (LPCSTR)(INT_PTR)(ID_MENU_DELETE - 1);
                cmi.lpParameters = NULL;
                cmi.lpDirectory = NULL;
                cmi.nShow = SW_SHOWNORMAL;
                cmi.dwHotKey = 0;
                cmi.hIcon = NULL;

                BOOL bUndoDel = FALSE;
                if (!(GetKeyState(VK_SHIFT) & SHIFTED))
                {
                    bUndoDel = TRUE;
                }
                hr = pcm->InvokeCommand (&cmi);


                if (FAILED(hr))
                {
                    _com_error error(hr);
                    LPCTSTR errorText = error.ErrorMessage();

                    AfxMessageBox(_T("Unable to perform action"));
                }
}
```

Comment: There are a couple of important pieces of information missing from your question. What is the file that you are trying to delete and where is the code for the `ID_MENU_DELETE` command handler. If the command handler is called but fails it's helpful to see what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

I had discovered the same problem and posted the details and solution at [Microsoft Visual Studio Language forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/230e7613-ffb4-4e58-b2ff-d3f9eae57412/cmfcshelllistctrloncontextmenu-delete-context-menu-handler-does-not-work-in-windows-7) and [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/792003/cmfcshelllistctrl-oncontextmenu-delete-context-menu-handler-does-not-work-in-windows-7).

In a nutshell, this line...

```
    cmi.hwnd = (HWND) GetParent();
```

...should be replaced with:

```
    cmi.hwnd = GetParent()->GetSafeHwnd();
```

Even though the casting of a CWnd* to an HWND yields an identical numerical value, for some unknown reason however, it yields different results between Windows XP (where it works) and Windows 7 (where it doesn't). Using GetSafeHwnd() fixes the problem so that the 'Delete File' confirmation dialog box now is displayed. It also works on Windows XP.